# Imágen con triángulo en CSS

Tags: html, css

Me preguntaba si como se podía hacer algo como lo que muestro en la siguiente captura. Es un `div` con un **background-img** al parecer, y tiene un triangulo de un pseudoelemento que también tiene un **background-img**, que no es simplemente eso, porque es re facil de hacer, lo que se complica es a la hora de hacer que ambos background image estén unidos. Se lo puede encontrar en Facebook al hacer hover sobre un nombre de usuario, es como una imágen con un triangulo que tiene la continuación de la foto que tiene la imágen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer por `background-image`, lo puedes hacer. Simplemente como te aconsejaron, usa `background-position` y ajusta el pseudo-elemento a la misma posición y con el mismo tamaño al otro elemento. Eso sí, tendrás si o si, que usar **`clip-path`** para darle la forma al triángulo, ya que por la forma tradicional (usando bordes) no te servirá como imagen de fondo y aún así tendrás problemas porque el tamaño de la imagen del padre determinará la del hijo, yo usare cover, pero por este ejemplo, pero si el elemento no cubre el 100% del ancho de la ventana tendrás que ponerle otra medida (no en porcentajes) a la imagen de fondo usando, **`background-size`**. Ejemplo:

```css
div{
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/600/400/?random);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-image: inherit; /*hereda la misma imagen del padre*/
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
  background-position: -100px 0px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hola
</div>
```

Pero ya que estas usando `clip-path`, te recomiendo recortar en forma de triángulo la parte de arriba del contenedor de la imagen, eso te ahorrara tener que usar más estilos innecesarios y el pseudo-elemento.:

```
.elemento{
  clip-path: 
     polygon(
      0 7px, 
/*coordenada punto 1, empiezo la coordenada en 7px porque es la altura del triangulo */
      100px 7px, 
/*coordenada punto 2, parte izquierda de la base del triángulo*/
      105px 0px, 
/*coordenada 3 punta triangulo*/
      110px 7px, 
/*coordenada punto 4, parte derecha de la base del triangulo*/
      100% 7px, 
/*coordenada punto 5*/      
      100% 100%, /*coordenada punto 6*/      
      0 100% /*coordenada punto 7*/
    );
}
```

```css
div{
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/600/400/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  clip-path: 
    polygon(
      0 7px, /*coordenada punto 1*/
      100px 7px, /*coordenada punto 2*/
      105px 0px, /*coordenada 3 punta triangulo*/
      110px 7px, /*coordenada punto 4*/
      100% 7px, /*coordenada punto 5*/      
      100% 100%, /*coordenada punto 6*/      
      0 100% /*coordenada punto 7*/
    );
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hola
</div>
```

Ya si tienes un contenido y no quieres que se vea recortado, solo tienes que usar padding-top para ajustarlo al recorte, es decir, cómo el triangulo mide 7px de alto, el padding sería igual.

---

Ahora ya que estamos, podemos automatizar un poco más las medidas del triángulo, usando las **variables css** y la **función css `calc`**. Ejemplo:

```css
div{
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/600/400/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  max-height: 50vh;
  
/*=============================
AQUI EMPIEZAN LAS VARIABLES CSS
===============================*/
  
  /*Altura en Y del triangulo*/
  --y: 25px; 
  /*Base de la derecha del triangulo*/
  --x1: 100px; 
  /*Ancho del triangulo*/
  --w: 40px; 

/*Las siguientes dos medidas se calcularan solas, 
* no hay que moverlas a menos que quieras*/

  /*Base de la izquierda del triangulo*/
  --x2: calc( var(--x1) + var(--w) ); 
  /*Punta del triangulo*/
  --punta: calc( var(--x1) + (var(--w) / 2) ); 

/*=============================
AQUI TERMINAN LAS VARIABLES CSS
===============================*/
  
  /*determina donde emieza el contenido segun la aultura del triangulo*/
  padding-top: var(--y); 
  clip-path: 
    polygon(
      0 var(--y), /*coordenada punto 1*/
      var(--x1) var(--y), /*coordenada punto 2*/
      var(--punta) 0, /*coordenada 3 punta triangulo*/
      var(--x2) var(--y), /*coordenada punto 4*/
      100% var(--y), /*coordenada punto 5*/      
      100% 100%, /*coordenada punto 6*/      
      0 100% /*coordenada punto 7*/
    );
}






/*Todo lo de aquí abajo lo puedes obviar*/
style{
  display: block;
  background: darkcyan;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
style:focus{ background: black; }
pre{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hola
</div>
Prueba a editar la siguientes variables y verás la magia:
<pre> <style contenteditable>div{
    /*¿Cual es la Altura del triángulo?*/
    --y: 20px;
    /*¿Cuanto mide el ancho del triángulo?*/
    --w: 30px;
    /*¿Donde Empieza  el triángulo?*/
    --x1: 20%; 
  }
</style> </pre>
```

Si te quedaron dudas, no dudes en usar la caja de comentarios.

Comment: Hola, es una buena manera también, me gusta, pero CREO, si no me equivoco al ver el código, que si el fondo de la página no fuera de un color plano, esto se vería mal.  Como por ejemplo agregando, como hice yo, un body background-image, como para simular un fondo dinámico al que ajustarse en lugar de un color plano.
`body {
  background-image: url('https://orthodoxcityhermit.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/tree1.jpg');
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}`
Como te comentaba, CREO que no resultaría, quizás estoy equivocado.
Saludos.

Comment: Si, obviamente depende del diseño, si no tuviera un color plano o la imagen de fondo (si la hay) no tiene suficiente contraste con el triángulo, se perdería el triángulo, aunque se podría solucionar usando bordes o con sombras.

Comment: Está bien, no entendía porque no los bordes, aunque nunca usé bordes, sino rotaba el elemento del before en un 50% para que quede como triangulo, pero desde devtools me dí cuenta que  era porque sino la imágen quedaría rotada también y no encajaría a la perfección.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez Ya que me surgió esta pregunta, y si no te molesta por supuesto, ¿Me podrías explicar si se puede hacer un triangulo como una media luna con clip-path, o sea como triangulo comido en forma redondeada por la mitad?

Comment: **No, con *clip-path* de momento no se puede**, se podría hacer usando **border-radius** y **border**, pero como ya debes haber intuido estas opciones no cuentan porque no pueden usarse imágenes de fondo. Otra opción podría ser usar mascaras svg para lograr esa forma, pero no lo he hecho nunca, se que se puede, pero no logro entender como sería.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que te vendría bien usar [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)  El cual deberías mover de acuerdo a la posición de tu triángulo.

Por lo que pusiste ya sabes hacer la figura, pero dejo un ejemplo completo donde ajusté la imagen de la sección donde va el texto, para que baje 5 pixeles, que es la altura del triángulo, y el triángulo lo moví 20 pixeles que es la distancia al margen izquierdo del diálogo.

En otras palabras, desplacé hacia abajo la posición inicial de la imagen que va en el diálogo con respecto a la altura del triángulo y ajusté hacia la izquierda la imagen que va en el triángulo, compensando el desplazamiento del triángulo con respecto al diálogo.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://orthodoxcityhermit.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/tree1.jpg');
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.dialogo,
.dialogo-inner {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png');
    background-position: top -5px left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dialogo:after,
.dialogo:before,
.dialogo-inner:after,
.dialogo-inner:before {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png');
  background-position:-20px 0px;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
}
.dialogo-inner {
  color: #444;
  padding: 20px;
}
.dialogo-inner:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 17px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.dialogo-inner:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 33px;
  right: 0;
}
.dialogo:before {
  top: -5px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogo">
  <div class="dialogo-inner" style="color:white;">
    COSAS!
    <br>cosas cosas cosas cosas
    <br>cosas cosas cosas cosas
    <br>cosas cosas cosas cosas
    <br>cosas cosas cosas cosas
    <br>cosas cosas cosas cosas
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que cambies la fuente de donde lees la imagen porque se cayo

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Vale, gracias :D